# Cows as symbols of Wisdom

Tags: comparative, irish, vedic

I just finished a very interesting article ["Boand" river-goddess and rebel"](https://earthandstarryheaven.com/2017/03/29/boand/) that talks about the bovine origin of her name, and makes a good case for cows as a symbol of wisdom in Irish lore.

The article also references the Vedas, and my first thought, per the author's revelation of the etymology of Boand as "bó" (cow) +"vinda" (bright or wise), was of [Govinda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Govinda).

I'm looking for other mythological references that link cows to wisdom.

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be something to the Govinda idea, and the "white/wise" also links her to the Irish hero Finn, [whose enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmon_of_Knowledge) came about because of her transgression.

Her wisdom could also come from being a river-goddess, like the Indian [Saraswati](http://www.sanatansociety.org/hindu_gods_and_goddesses/saraswati.htm) and Persian [Anahita](http://www.cais-soas.com/CAIS/Religions/iranian/anahita.htm) were also goddesses of abundance, wisdom, and rivers. Either way, I do feel she has a wisdom component that's often overlooked.

I've come back to add that some trace her back to a proto-Indo-European *[Gwouwinda](https://everything2.com/title/Indo-European+Mythology), whose Celtic avatars would be Boand, Brigit and maybe Damona. Saraswati may have had a cow aspect, since the Rig Veda (RV 9.67.32) says she makes milk and butter flow. I haven't been able to find anything bovine for Anahita.